# Why does this lambda function return the wrong answer

Tags: c#, arrays, lambda

I'm trying to convert an int array in C# to a normal integer
It works for most numbers but when i have the following code:

```
int[] digits = new int[] { 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0 };
int bignumber = digits.Select((t, i) => t * Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(10, digits.Length - i - 1))).Sum();
```

it returns 1286608618 instead of 9876543210

I imagine it has something to do with the length of the array? But I don't understand how... If I remove the 0 on the end and make the array 9 numbers long it works fine. Stick any number in the 10th position and it breaks again.

Comment: change int to long

Comment: Replace the lambda with a named method and use the debugger to see what it actually does. You don't need us to tell you what code is doing when you have a debugger

Comment: Also, don't use `Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(`. `Math.Pow` uses doubles to do the calculation and you could end up with rounding issues. Use a simple `int` or `long` `pow` method. It's simple to write. `long pow(long x, long n) => n == 0 ? 1 : x * pow(x, n - 1);`. Of course, this is only valid for non-negative `n`.

Comment: Or, just avoid invoking powers at all: `long bignumber = digits.Select(x => (long)x).Aggregate((x, y) => x * 10 + y);`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's a very interesting and better way to get this working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sum is going out of range of max Int32, which is `2147483647`. Use Int64 (long) instead:

```
int[] digits = new int[] { 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0 };
long bignumber = digits.Select((t, i) => t * Convert.ToInt64(Math.Pow(10, digits.Length - i - 1))).Sum();
```

Comment: Ah... of course... thank you! Beginner coder here !